# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token после того как пытаюсь запустить файл с помощью node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

После того как пробую запустить файл, выдает ошибку

```
D:\NewExpressProject\app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��l
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
```

Код файла:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
   res.send("home page");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log("server has started");
});
```

Ноут на 10 винде.
Переустанавливал node не помогло.
Версия node.js - 10.12.0 , версия npm - 6.4.1
Пробовал версию node.js - 8.12.0 - та же проблема

ПК на 7 винде всё работает.
Версия node.js - 10.9.0 , версия npm - 6.2.0

Comment: Похоже на BOM, но нода вроде должна его выпиливать

Comment: [в этот коде нет никаких проблем](https://repl.it/@norbornen/HandmadeTrickyColdfusion). судя по ошибке проблема может быть в каком-то специфическом символе в app.js. я бы рекомендовал установить редактор кода, удалить app.js и создать этот файл с помощью редактора кода. сам js-код лучше бы скопировать прямо отсюда

Comment: Проблема была в том что создавал файл app.js с помощью команды в терминале dir > app.js.
При создании файла file -> new file и т.д. всё нормально.
Но на ПК и с dir > app.js работало - странно.